# Why am I getting a deadlock with a read/write mutex going from write->read->write?

Tags: c++, multithreading, tbb

I have some TBB code where I'm using a R/W lock to implement a barrier that's sometimes getting deadlocked and I'm not sure why. I'm guessing it has something to do with the internal implementation of a R/W lock. Pseudocode below.

```
tbb::queuing_rw_mutex mutex;
tbb::parallel_for
  (0, array.Num(),
   [&](int i)
   {
     tbb::queuing_rw_mutex::scoped_lock lock(mutex); // write lock
     ...
     lock.downgrade_to_read();
     ...
     lock.upgrade_to_write();
     ...
     // implicit lock.unlock()
   });
```

Any guesses why I'm getting a deadlock sometimes waiting for the first write lock?

Comment: Make a [mcve]. Could your homemade `array` be the cause? Who knows....?

Comment: Does the code make (directly or indirectly) other invocations of TBB's parallel API while holding the write lock?